# Get Controls collections from aspx that contains 2 calls for same ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey there, I'm in a bit of a pinch and i wold appreciate a little help from anyone.:D

I have a aspx page that registers a ascx control that contains a number of other asp controls.This ascx control is called in 2 places in the same aspx.Something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<table ID="Tbl1" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <cc1:TagName1 ID="tag1" runat="server" />
        </td>            
    </tr>
</table>
<Table ID="tbl2" runat="server">    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <cc1:TagName1 ID="tag2" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>    
</Table>
</asp:Content>
```

My question is : How can i get in the code behind of the ASCX file the collection of controls that are contained in the "tag1" control and then the collection from "tag2" control ??

I tried something like this:

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ControlCollection collection = this.Page.FindControl("Tbl1").Controls;
            foreach (Control cont in collection)
            {
                lbl1.Text = cont.ClientID + " ";
            }

            ControlCollection collection2 = this.Page.FindControl("Tbl2").Controls;
            foreach (Control cont in collection2)
            {
                lbl2.Text = cont.ClientID + " ";
            }
        }
```

but it cannot find the "Tbl1" and "Tbl2" controls.I suspect this is because i need to indicate the ClientID instead of the "ID", but I have no idea how. 
(the label controls are only for listing the collection of controls found)

If anyone has any idea on how to do this I wold very much appreciate some help.:D

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were over-complicating stuff.

It works as easy as (works on my computer):

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control cont in tag1.Controls)
    {
        lbl1.Text += cont.ClientID + " ";
    }

    foreach (Control cont in tag2.Controls)
    {
        lbl2.Text += cont.ClientID + " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason `FindControl` is failing is because you have a master page. Rick Strahl wrote a blog [post](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/5127.aspx) about this problem in which he comes up with a nice `FindControlRecursive` function that you could use. In your case you could call it like this:

```
ControlCollection controls = FindControlRecursive(this.Page, "Tbl1").Controls;
```

Taken from Rick Strahl's [blog](http://west-wind.com/weblog/):

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds a Control recursively. Note finds the first match and exists
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ContainerCtl"></param>
/// <param name="IdToFind"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
{
    if (Root.ID == Id)
        return Root;

    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
    {
        Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
        if (FoundCtl != null)
            return FoundCtl;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this when you know which user control it's within?

Comment: Haven't tried this yet. I will give it a shot this evening when i get off from work. 10x a lot. :)

Comment: It works , but not exactly how I wished it wold.Is it possible to get the collection of controls generated from the ascx for each call of the ascx control??(this function only gets the "cc1:Tagname1" controls, I want to get the collection of controls that is contained in these controls("cc1:Tagname1")).
10x for your time.:)